# Facebook until empty results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Anybody knows why i get no results back when i add the untill parameter in facebook?

Requested url: https://graph.facebook.com/FBID/home?limit=25&until=1388688636

How do i replicate this:

1. Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
2. Execute the above url (FBID/home?limit=25&until=1388688636)
3. In the returned results go to the bottom and click the link that got the json key: "next" (looks like: "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/FBID/home?limit=25&until=1388688639")
4. The returned result is: 
   {
     "data": [
     ]
   }

i searched for ages about this problem and could not find it, the only thing i can come up with is that Facebook only returns posts since the permission accept for the Access Token, another cause could be that Facebook is broken.

Comment: I was also sporadically receiving empty results sets with the "until" param as well. It may just be the Graph Explorer tool. It does seem to fix itself if you re-request an access token.

Comment: I tried re-requesting an access token but that did not solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard (albeit undocumented) behavior. The empty data array shows up when you try to access an object that has its privacy settings configured to not let third party apps read it, and it's also what's being displayed after you've reached the end of all public records of the current user.

You just have to deal with it. Keep looping over the next result while `data != empty` is true.

Update: This could also be related to an open issue Facebook is aware about, namely broken pagination. The problem seems to be "dead ends". You can read more [about it here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/276689195769156?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52c5f9fc3ffbb4098225286) and try fiddling around with the timestamp and limit parameters of the request.

Comment: I am 100% sure that there are over 3000 posts for that users so i think it is quite impossible to get no results back with an until because of what you said.

Comment: Please note the "public records" part of my answer. If what you're saying is correct, then the posts you are trying to access has different privacy settings than the ones you _can_ access. What kind of access token are you using?

Comment: I got these permissions:

create_note, export_stream, friends_likes, friends_photo_video_tags, friends_photos, friends_relationship_details, friends_status, friends_videos, manage_notifications, photo_upload, publish_actions, publish_stream, read_stream, share_item, status_update, user_friends, user_photos, video_upload

Comment: Are you using your own app in the API Explorer or is _Application_ set to Graph API Explorer? I'm not sure what the logic is behind it, but when using my own application I get a lot of results that the Graph API Explorer "app" does not, even though they have the same permissions.

Comment: I am testing it with both my own App and the Api explorer, they both give the same result (empty results on the next until page). The weird thing also is that it doesn't work on this account but it does on several other accounts.

Comment: Just read your answer, thanks for finding it :) i believe that it is indeed a problem at Facebook their side, hopefully they will fix it.